# Color picker in dhtmlx layout

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I am using colorpicker tool http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxColorPicker/  in Dhtmlx project but it doesn't work. I put it inside a cell layout. If you try to choose color it is totally blocked. Are there any other way to put it into layout? Here a live example: http://www.felpone.netsons.org/designed/

I understood the reason: the canvas inside the center cell overlap the left cell and if you try to click on colorpicker you are clicking on canvas and not on colorpicker. Now the issue is: I can't resize the canvas, how can I put left cell over of canvas? I tried with z-index but doesn't work.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //the code of your application

    dhtmlx.image_path = "codebase/imgs/";
      dhtmlxEvent(window,"load",function(){ 


var main_layout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject(document.body, '3W');
main_layout.cells("b").attachObject("ThreeJS");
main_layout.cells("a").attachObject("colorPicker");

var a = main_layout.cells('a');
//a.collapse();
a.setWidth('400');
a.fixSize(1,0);


var b = main_layout.cells('b');
b.setWidth('600');
b.hideHeader();


var c = main_layout.cells('c');
c.setWidth('350');
c.hideHeader();
c.fixSize(1,0);


var toolbar_1 = main_layout.attachToolbar();
toolbar_1.setIconSize(32);
toolbar_1.setIconsPath('./codebase/imgs/32/');

toolbar_1.loadStruct('./data/toolbar.xml', function() {});
toolbar_1.setAlign("right");

var myColorPicker = new dhtmlXColorPicker({
parent : "colorPicker",
color : "#0000ff",
custom_colors : true
  });

});









</script>

<div id="toolbarObj" ></div>
<div id="colorPicker" style="">ciao</div>
<div  id="ThreeJS" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need separated colorpicker over the layout, you just need to set z-index for it. I.e.:

```
<div id="colorPicker" style="position:absolute;top:150px;left:200px;z-index: 10"></div>
```